# Using Random Number inside of Switch Statement Cases

Tags: c++, random

I am having a problem with a certain section of code that is supposed to give an enemy a random set of items based on their preset difficulty level. I am using a modified template version of Bjorne's random function. When I used his original version I still had the problem:

[Random number generator code from Stroustrup:](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-random)

```
template<class T>
T rand_num(const T & low, const T & high)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re{};
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{ low,high });
}
```

When I test the section by making an `EnemyAI` object that encapsulates the `OffensiveEntity` and setting the difficulty to, say, 1, it always sets the random number to 1 and always chooses, in this case, the Health potion. If I were to set the second `if` statement to a condition of `if (tempRandom == 1)` it would choose the stick.

```
void EnemyAI::Equip()
{
    m_offensiveEntity->ClearItems();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> tempItems;

    int tempRandom = 0;

    switch (m_difficultyLevel)
    {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    {
        tempRandom = rand_num<int>(1, 4);
        if ((tempRandom == 1) || (tempRandom == 2) || (tempRandom == 3) || (tempRandom == 4))
            tempItems.push_back(CreateTempItem("Health Potion : HP", 3, 3, 
-10, Result::Effect::nothing));
        if (tempRandom == 3)
            tempItems.push_back(CreateTempItem("Wooden Stick : DMG", 5, 2, 10, Result::Effect::nothing, 3, 13, Result::Effect::nothing));
        break;
    }
    case 2: ... etc
```

What's the cause of this problem? Here's the output:

```
Health Potion : HP name
3 durability
-10 total damage
3 energy cost
0 effect
```

When typing in this:

```
int main()
{
     std::shared_ptr<EnemyAI> offensiveEntityInterface =
         std::make_shared<EnemyAI>(EnemyAI("Dank Memerson", 50, 1));

     offensiveEntityInterface->Equip();
    for (auto & i : offensiveEntityInterface->GetEquiped())
    {
        std::cout << i->GetName() << " name \n";
        std::cout << i->GetHP() << " durability \n";
        std::shared_ptr<const Result> tempResult = i->Use();
        std::cout << tempResult->m_totalDamage << " total damage \n";
        std::cout << tempResult->m_energyCost << " energy cost \n";
        std::cout << tempResult->m_effect << " effect \n";
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Heres the source code in a pastebin
https://pastebin.com/F4Q74Gc6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your engine is unseeded, and is thus using a default value that is the same every time you run your program. To make sure that it's different on each run, you need to seed it.

Some old-guard programmers usually recommend getting the current system clock as an integer and using that as the seed, but C++11 specifically recommends you use `std::random_device`, which will attempt to grab truly random numbers by reading temperature sensors in the CPU or by some similar means, and will fall-back to a pseudorandom method (like grabbing the system clock or some other method) if it's unable to do that.

```
template<class T>
T rand_num(const T & low, const T & high)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re{std::random_device{}()};
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{ low,high });
}
```

Also, your code is going to create a new engine for each type you use to generate numbers with. Like, if you invoke `rand_num<int32_t>`, `rand_num<int64_t>`, `rand_num<int16_t>`, that's three different engines that will be allocated and maintained on the stack by your runtime. Unless you feel you definitely need to do that, you're better off writing code that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
T rand_num(std::default_random_engine & re, const T & low, const T & high)
{
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{ low,high });
}

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine engine{std::random_device{}()};
    /*...*/
    int val = rand_num<int>(engine, 1, 4);
    /*...*/
}
```

Many C++ implementations map `std::default_random_engine` to `std::mt19937`, which is a pretty heavy object, consisting of a lot of state that has to be allocated and generated whenever one is created. Making sure you're always reusing the engine can save some time.

Comment: So your second example isn't necessary if you declare the default random engine as static like in the first example? As, calling the function with the std::default_random_engine engine object with std::random_device in the second function creates the exact same result as initializing the static std::default_random_engine engine object in the function and calling that one?

Comment: @Chopdops The output between the two versions isn't meaningfully different in terms of what they "do", i.e. they both work to generate random numbers in a specified range. The difference is that the first version will create new instantiations of `std::default_random_engine` for each unique type the function is invoked with, whereas the second version will only create one instantiation, regardless of how many types you use (unless you manually create more engines yourself).

Comment: @Chopdops The reason why that matters is that 'engine' objects are pretty expensive to construct, especially if `std::default_random_engine` maps to `std::mt19937`, which is standard on many C++ implementations. If you know that you'll only ever invoke `rand_num<int>` and won't invoke any other version of that function, then the difference doesn't matter and you can happily use the first version. But if not, then you'll suffer performance penalties the first time a type is used, each time.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to encapsulate this in a class? As storing the default random engine as a static member variable to remove explicit declaration of the engine as a (almost) globally scoped variable?

Comment: @Chopdops Yes. Encapsulating all of this in a class is a very good idea.